# superclasses in generic classes in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

This is my first time here, but I do my best to describe my problem:

I have an abstract class `A`. I also have abstract classes `B` and `C` extending `A`. Then I have classes extending `B` or `C`.

Now I have a generic class only accepting classes extending `A`.
(`class XYZ<ABC extends A>…`)

Now I basically want to create a method that works with the generic class, but only with instances that use a class extending `B`.

I tried something like this:

```
public void method(XYZ<B> t){}
```

This sadly didn't work. The IDE wanted me to have either the type of `t` or the other way around.

Now the questions:
Why does this not work? It seems that it wouldn't cause any problems, because a subclass has to provide all methods from the superclass.
Is there a way around this except of making a method for every single subclass of B or changing the type of the object i want to use?

example code:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Abc> foo = new ArrayList<>();
    xyz(foo);
}
private void xyz(ArrayList<B> abs){}


private static abstract class  A{}
private static abstract class  B extends A{}
private static abstract class  C extends A{}
private static class Abc extends B{}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please show all code necessary to reproduce that error. See [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: uh, sry, late here:"[...] to either change the type of t the the objects type or[...]"

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you post some actual code?

Comment: Here's an example on Ideone which follows your description and compiles: http://ideone.com/0vE3N3. So again, per my earlier comment, please update your question with a more clear code example.

Comment: @Radiodef The method is supposed to be inside `class XYZ<ABC extends A>` as far as I understood it.

Comment: @Gendarme doesn't matter.

Comment: Added some code and yes, my English grammar knowledge is not the best.

Comment: Sry, I can't compile it per console on this pc, but eclipse tells me that I should either change the method to private void xyz(ArrayList<Abc> abs){} or foo to ArrayList<B>

Comment: see if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/2891664 (possible duplicate)

Comment: This will help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html In short: `Abc` is a subclass of `B`, but `ArrayList<Abc>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<B>`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found the solution by the related stuff, that i couldnt find the last 2 hours... well, thanks anyways and sry for stealing your time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Abc> foo = new ArrayList<>();
        xyz(foo);
    }

    private static <T extends B> void xyz(ArrayList<T> abs){
        System.out.print("running xyz");
    }


    private static abstract class  A{}
    private static abstract class  B extends A{}
    private static abstract class  C extends A{}
    private static class Abc extends B{}
}
```

Seems to be what you are aiming for. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more information.